# check if joystick magnitude is increasing

Tags: unity, c#, vector, coroutines, joystick

I use joystick mechanic. What I want to do is:

- Translating my object forward when my `joystickInput.magnitude` is increasing.
- Translating backward when my `joystickInput.magnitude` is decreasing.

I need to know if my `joystickInput.magnitude` is increasing or decreasing, but I couldn't find any idea for how to do it.

I tried to keep previous magnitude for comparing them, but since there is an equality condition in the *2nd if statement*, after `magnitude = joystickInput.magnitude` it goes into this *if statement* again and again, so in every frame it just goes into *else statement* for **once** and almost never goes to the **(-)direction**.

If I don't add the equality sign, then it goes into else statement again and again as the same as previous above version.

So, what I have is this (not working as expected) ;

```
private void Update()
{
    joystickInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);

    if(joystickInput.magnitude > 0.1f && joystickInput.magnitude < 0.9f)
    {
        Debug.Log("joystickInput.magnitude " + joystickInput.magnitude);
        Debug.Log("magnitude " + magnitude);
        if (joystickInput.magnitude >= magnitude)
        {
            Debug.Log("increasing");
            magnitude = joystickInput.magnitude;
            foreach (GameObject obj in spheres)
            {
                Vector3 direction = (obj.transform.position - centerPoint.position);
                obj.transform.position += direction * (joystickInput.magnitude + 2) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log("decreasing");
            magnitude = joystickInput.magnitude;
            foreach (GameObject obj in spheres)
            {
                Vector3 direction = (obj.transform.position - centerPoint.position);
                obj.transform.position += -direction * (joystickInput.magnitude + 2) * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to compare current magnitude and previous one, but it is always same. I couldnt compare them.

Comment: You might want to do the check _before_ you overwrite the value stored in `savedMagnitude`.

Comment: @Vaillancourt I edited the question

Comment: So you only want to update when the player is moving the joystick. Not when held stationary? In that case you just have to compare the joysticks current magnitude with the magnitude it had last frame. Here you are only updating the previous magnitude when a change is detected. It should always be updated!

Comment: @Sandsten if I understood correctly, I edited it like : I does **magnitude = joystickInput.magnitude;** only at the last line of update. But nothing has changed, it goes into if statement, more than else statement

Comment: @Sandsten  [![here is the video gif][1]][1]
when joystick is moving to center, the game object is integrated but for a short time, and then it starts to disintegrate again
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EPpp.gif

Comment: What is the desired effect? To me it looks kind of correct. The spheres move relative to the speed you are moving the joystick away and towards its center. Or if you want the spheres to be far out when the magnitude is large and together when it's 0? Then you can just set their position to be equal to your direction vector times the joystick magnitude.

Comment: @Sandsten I want exactly spheres to be far out when the magnitude is large and together when it goes to 0. But in this case "set their position to be equal to your direction vector times the joystick magnitude", as I understood, u are saying "dont use if/else statement and write only **direction vector times the joystick magnitude**", if this is what u are saying, how can it does the integration case (being together again) while magnitude gets smaller? Because "direction vector times the joystick magnitude" will never gets negative value. Am I wrong? Because joystick magnitude range is (0,1)

Comment: @Sandsten I mean, direction value needs to get minus sign at some point so that all spheres can go back to their initial position. But the thing is I couldnt find a way for  implementing "when joys. magnitude gets bigger / smaller" :(

Comment: @Sandsten what I want is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2iJx.gif  as a disintegration case. The integration case is the reverse of this gif. (please ignore the forward down direction)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have unity on my current machine, so I can't test this, but I would try this.

```
float previousMagnitude = 0.0f;
private void Update()
{
    var joystickInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
    float currentMagnitude = joystickInput.magnitude;
    if(0.1f < currentMagnitude && currentMagnitude < 0.9f)
    {
        if(currentMagnitude > previousMagnitude)
        {
            Debug.Log("increasing");

        }
        else if(currentMagnitude < previousMagnitude)
        {
            Debug.Log("decreasing");

        }
        previousMagnitude = currentMagnitude;
    }
}
```